# Getting IP address from HTTP POST request using Python

Tags: python, http-post

I am using a python script to do my webserver using the `BaseHTTPServer` module. Below is my code for the server:

```
import string,cgi,time
from os import curdir, sep
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
#import pri

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        try:
        if self.path.endswith("/"):
        f = open(curdir + sep + "index.html")
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type',    'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("<HTML> GET OK.<BR>")
        f.close()
        return

            return

        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)


    def do_POST(self):
        global rootnode
        try:
            ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
            if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
                query=cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type',    'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        file = query.get('file')
        self.wfile.write("<HTML> POST OK.<BR>")
        f = open("data.zip", "wb")
            f.write(file[0])
            f.close()
            print("File received.")
        return

        except :
            pass

def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), MyHandler)
        print 'started httpserver...'
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C received, shutting down server'
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there anyway to get the IP address of a POST request when my server receives it? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to get their IP address with `self.client_address[0]`.

Comment: When I do `print self.client_address`, it gives me an IP address and a number. Is that the port number?

Comment: @androidnoob: Yes, the second number is the client's port. If you want just the IP address, tack `[0]` onto the end.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your prompt answer! I can't thank you enough for it!

Comment: Hmm.. can you explain why I always get the value `192.168.2.50` no matter where the client is connecting from?

Comment: @pir: You've probably got a reverse proxy running in front of your application. Some proxies add an `X-Forwarded-For` header that provides the IP address of the client that connected to _it_.