# Include IP of the customer on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, python-3.x

I need to include the IP address of the customer when  the customer submit the forms in my website?Is this possible using python or javascript without using any third party scripts?To pass the IP address along with the form details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Comment: You don't put the IP into the form. The server gets the IP from the network. What python module are you using to get the form data, it should have a method to get the client's IP?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389691/getting-ip-address-from-http-post-request-using-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575722/how-to-get-a-viewers-ip-address-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Add an input field, and set it to `display: none`:

```
<input type="text" name="IP Address" id="visitor_ip-2" value="IP" style="display: none;">
```

add this js code to fetch the ip address

```
// Function to retrieve the visitor's IP address
function getVisitorIP2(callback) {
    var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr2.open('GET', 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json', true);
    xhr2.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr2.readyState === 4 && xhr2.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText);
            callback(response.ip);
        }
    };
    xhr2.send();
}

// Populate the hidden field with the visitor's IP address
getVisitorIP2(function(ip) {
    document.getElementById('visitor_ip-2').value = ip;
});
```

Comment: Your code could use some formatting help there.  I tried to fix the indentation, but I'm still seeing what *appears* to be a dangling, extra parenthesis at the end.